# Motion detection using a sequence of images

Tags: image-processing, motion-detection

I have a sequence of N images. By calculating the mean and std (µ,σ) of every pixel of the image in the range of N images, I obtain a mean and an std matrices of the size of the image, I'd like to use the information of (µ,σ) to be able to deduce the pixels that are part of the background and that are still, and therefore detect the moving pixel and thus objects.

How can I do that using (µ,σ)?

Comment: It'd be helpful to have a code example either here or in a playground like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Deviation should be zero or close to zero (in case we are talking some video feed with enviromental noise) for those pixels which didn't change much, therefore are part of the background. It would only work for very static camera.

Comment: What libraries are you working on ? You know you get these with OpenCV out of the box?

Comment: I am using Matlab with mean() and std() functions, I just like to use the results to deduce information about the moving objetcs.